# QPushButton stylesheet when setCheckable(true)

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qpushbutton

When I use

```
myButton->setCheckable(true);
```

There is -I don't know how to call it- a sort of grid :

[image: myImage]

Is it possible to not have this grid and here just my green background ?

Comment: `myButton->setStyleSheet("QPushButton:checked{
    background-color: green; }");` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `checked` property:

```
QPushButton:checked{
  background-color: ...
  border: none;
}
```

Same applies for `pressed` if you want to alter that too.

**Note:** You can read all about the properties [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/stylesheet-reference.html) (just search for `QPushButton` to find the properties that are part of the button. Removing the border seems to be necessary based on the documentation (otherwise the background colour might not be applied).